# Bootstrap resizing input & text(right of input)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, window-resize

I'm stuck for a while on a scaling problem ...

When i resize the window(mobile) the "%" go below the input even with the 80% width, idk why he don't stay at right...

```html
<html>


 <head>
     <!--<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <head>
     
     <body>
   <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row form-inline text-center">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3 form-inline text-center">
                          <label for="a">A</label></br>      
                          <input id="a" name="a" type="number" class="form-control" style="width:80%;"/><b>%</b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                          <label for="b">B</label></br>  
                          <input id="b" name="b" type="number" class="form-control" style="width:80%"/> <b>%</b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                          <label for="c">C</label></br>  
                          <input id="c" name="c" type="number" class="form-control" style="width:80%"/> <b>%</b>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                          <label for="c">D</label> </br>      
                          <input id="c" name="c" type="number" class="form-control" style="width:80%"/> <b>%</b>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <body>
</html>
```

if anyone knows what's wrong ...

Comment: can you please explain more about it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The '%' is taking up more then 20% of the width on small screens. A nice solution would be to use input addons available in bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic